# Tab size wrong with EditorConfig and SublimeText 3

Tags: sublimetext3, editorconfig

With SublimeText3 my .editorconfig file contains:

```
[*.{h,cc,cpp}]
indent_style = space
indent_size = 2
tab_width = 8
```

I would expect tab characters in a file to expand to 8 spaces, but I'm seeing them expand to only 2 spaces. Hitting tab correctly indents by 2 spaces.

Is there a way to make it work as desired? So that tab characters expand to 8 spaces? But hitting tab still inserts 2 spaces?

Comment: Not sure if its helpful, but `emacs` handles this situation exactly as you expect based on the same `.editorconfig` - so check with Sublime, the editor-config plugin or the editor itself isn't handling this situation.

Answer (score 2):

That's because you're using `indent_style = space` and providing `indent_size = 2`.
If you want your tabs to spand 8 spaces, then use `indent_size = 8`, but I'm pretty sure you don't want that!
In this case, since you want to work with tabs, then try this

```
[*.{h,cc,cpp}]
indent_style = tab
tab_width = 8
```

(Also its a good practice to check for mixed tabs and spaces in your files, that may lead to incorrect behavior in your config, which may not apply here, but it's a friendly reminder)

Comment: indent_size=2 with tab_width=8 describes to me exactly what I want, when I indent it inserts two spaces, when encountering a tab character it expands to 8 spaces. But doesn't seem to work. Converting everything to spaces would definitely be useful and solve the problem, but I'm not really at liberty to make large PR right now.

Comment: @Philip Can't get what you just said. You shouldn't ever use mixed tabs and spaces in your project files, chose one and stick with it. If you have a mix of both, then that part of your `.editorconfig` won't work at all. You can check for that by selecting all your code, and look for points and dashes in your indenting (points are spaces, dashes are tabs),

Comment: This is a large existing code base with a mix of tabs and spaces. The official policy is spaces only, two-space indent. But where there are tab characters they need to be expanded to 8 spaces to look right. I can't politically insist we un-tabify the whole thing, since I'm a minor contributor. Their editors must work correctly with the mix, or they'd never put up with the mess. The EditorConfig settings I suggested above, to me, would do the right thing. But I understand Sublime doesn't interpret them that way, so that's too bad. I will accept this answer as best if nothing new comes in soon.

Comment: You can always suggest them to start working on this (they should use a style guide). Also, you don't need the complete codebase to be changed for this, you can always create a new `.editorconfig` file on the folder you're working on besides the one in project's root. But that's it. That's how EditorConfig works depending on what `indent_style` you're using.

Comment: I don't want to be unhelpful - but there is a school of style thought with these two axioms - 1. "tab size and indent size are unrelated", 2. "tab size == 8 is a fundamental constant of the universe".  Editorconfig is there to allow _you_ to define policy with your source, not to decide that something should not be allowed.  Check in with Sublime, since this works as expected with other editors.